# Is there any efficient ways to set data to MapObject?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, algorithm

I want to remake and sort an array.
Is it possible to use "reduce" instead of "forEach" or "map" ?
return beeProps.valueInfos.reduce (reduce()) woule be great.

[Date,Onject] --->  [Number,Object] ---I would like to gether same "Number" Object to an array  ---> [Number ,Object[]]

I believe people in here are so smart... someone can find a good way.

```
//Sample IO

  type Info = {
    title: string;
    InfoMap: Map<Date, Slot>; 
  };

  type Slot =
  | {
      kind: "on";
    }
  | {
      kind: "off";
    };

    let date1 = new Date(1999, 11, 31, 20);        
    let date2 = new Date(1999, 11, 31, 21);        
    let date3 = new Date(1999, 11, 31, 22); 
    let date4 = new Date(1999, 11, 31, 23);  

    const sampleInfoDetailMap:Map<Date, Slot> = new Map();
    sampleInfoDetailMap.set(date1,{kind: 'on' as const})
    sampleInfoDetailMap.set(date2,{kind: 'on' as const})
    sampleInfoDetailMap.set(date3,{kind: 'off' as const})
    sampleInfoDetailMap.set(date4,{kind: 'on' as const})

    const sampleInfoDetailMap2:Map<Date, Slot> = new Map();
    sampleInfoDetailMap2.set(date1,{kind: 'on' as const})
    sampleInfoDetailMap2.set(date2,{kind: 'off' as const})
    sampleInfoDetailMap2.set(date3,{kind: 'off' as const})
    sampleInfoDetailMap2.set(date4,{kind: 'on' as const})

    console.log(date1.getTime());
    console.log(date2.getTime());
   let sampleInfo:Info = {title:"test1"  ,InfoMap:sampleInfoDetailMap}
   let sampleInfo2:Info = {title:"test2"  ,InfoMap:sampleInfoDetailMap2}
   let info:Info[] = new Array();

    //ideal Output is 
    //numer => Date.getTime() : number;
    //Map<number,Slot[]>
    const idealResult:Map<number,Slot[]> = new Map();

   //[946638000000 , [on,on]
    //[946641600000 , [on,off]
//note: 946638000000 is 1999, 11, 31, 20. 946641600000 is 1999, 11, 31, 21
```

Comment: Can you post sample input with a sample output?

Comment: I will prepare sample i/o . However, What I want to know is that It is possible or not... and that verification.

Comment: Can’t answer that bc It’s not clear what you’re after. Which is why I want to see sample input and output

Comment: I added the sample. please check it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from your question exactly what you're looking for, since the example code doesn't seem to specify the particular input and output.  Let me know if the following works for you:

```
const mapKeyMaps = <KI, KO, V>(
    keyMapper: (ki: KI) => KO,
    ...inputMaps: Map<KI, V>[]
): Map<KO, V[]> =>
    ([] as Array<[KI, V]>).concat(...inputMaps.map(m => Array.from(m.entries())))
        .map(([ki, v]) => [keyMapper(ki), v] as const)
        .reduce(
            (acc, [ko, v]) => ((acc.get(ko) || (acc.set(ko, []), acc.get(ko)!)).push(v), acc),
            new Map<KO, V[]>()
        );
```

which produces this output for your sample:

```
let info: Info[] = [sampleInfo, sampleInfo2];
const idealResult = mapKeyMaps((date) => date.getTime(), ...info.map(i => i.InfoMap))
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(idealResult.entries())));
/*
[
    [946688400000,[{"kind":"on"},{"kind":"on"}]],
    [946692000000,[{"kind":"on"},{"kind":"off"}]],
    [946695600000,[{"kind":"off"},{"kind":"off"}]],
    [946699200000,[{"kind":"on"},{"kind":"on"}]]
]
*/
```

If that works for you, I'll explain how `mapKeyMaps()` works.  If not, please edit the code in your question to constitute a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and maybe I can provide a better solution.  Either way, good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4GkCmBPAssiMC8MAPCgJIA0MKA8pQGoB8AFAFAzswDWmOSSaAJwBcMJpwCWIsgEoCDKrTYcAdKvFgkAVyi8II3iQoxGAbQC6LafuQlax8-PwMl7JuZgI8AQQECEGIhMyejMGaWVQMGAEKCZVZXUtHVxlRCQmODkYHz8MZQAzARA4DOU0MCgBcTQIJml66RcOdlTkJjcJSgA3M1knGBNubGR+ATFxaW6zDzxI6Ebm5uUBNAATTWA0VkWd0QRgYEpBkCm++Xb94GUAczRYzhBZAB8nvYPlCDuxE4Heykubl8HtIAIT1ZRaCAACyYXUmHgOkyauxgYDQAHcYAYaPQHHVkRxpABuFikqAYfgwUhgfIgAgwADeTSg4igABs0CJoFUwNcSc1qbTeNYkEQACIxNCUADKbJAUAYJIAviSWOTKbL5QQmq8mSiJGBViIAETgY38jhKnWMgnsA1GmCm-L5c1NFWkjmwVaSgCM9LRmIlUC2PoAnOHKD6fZQAMzRmAAJgADMSWJ6YN7gwn-RiYEGQ+HQ5H43HKAmfan05m0DGc4HJUwwxGYFHY-GEwnK3cM5KACx1vMNptFlsl9sx1MsOawCAIOBIDmCkBiu4IcRs4VYmz5mVyhUD3h1Emz+eLmnL1fr3gfL7V+MMrjqB0AcnAz5mMGnMCVjRPC7QS4rlAa4bsgN6xNWCaUA+9oiK+YDvp4n7gNA36-nO-6AZeoFIOBTDVjG0GPoacEgM6iGzChsA-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)